# I am getting wrong output here (assign cookies)

Tags: c

**Question:**
Assume you are an awesome parent and want to give your children some cookies. But, you should give each child at most one cookie.

Each child i has a greed factor g[i], which is the minimum size of a cookie that the child will be content with; and each cookie j has a size s[j]. If s[j] >= g[i], we can assign the cookie j to the child i, and the child i will be content. Your goal is to maximize the number of your content children and output the maximum number.

**For example:**

**Input:** g = [1,2,3], s = [1,1]

**Output:** 1

**Explanation:** You have 3 children and 2 cookies. The greed factors of 3 children are 1, 2, 3.
And even though you have 2 cookies, since their size is both 1, you could only make the child whose greed factor is 1 content.
You need to output 1.

**Question is to obtain the output for the below input:**

```
*g= 
[262,437,433,102,438,346,131,160,281,34,219,373,466,275,51,118,209,32,108,57,385,514,439,73,271,442,366,515,284,425,491,466,322,34,484,231,450,355,106,279,496,312,96,461,446,422,143,98,444,461,142,234,416,45,271,344,446,364,216,16,431,370,120,463,377,106,113,406,406,481,304,41,2,174,81,220,158,104,119,95,479,323,145,205,218,482,345,324,253,368,214,379,343,375,134,145,268,56,206]

*s=
[149,79,388,251,417,82,233,377,95,309,418,400,501,349,348,400,461,495,104,330,155,483,334,436,512,232,511,40,343,334,307,56,164,276,399,337,59,440,3,458,417,291,354,419,516,4,370,106,469,254,274,163,345,513,130,292,330,198,142,95,18,295,126,131,339,171,347,199,244,428,383,43,315,353,91,289,466,178,425,112,420,85,159,360,241,300,295,285,310,76,69,297,155,416,333,416,226,262,63,445,77,151,368,406,171,13,198,30,446,142,329,245,505,238,352,113,485,296,337,507,91,437,366,511,414,46,78,399,283,106,202,494,380,479,522,479,438,21,130,293,422,440,71,321,446,358,39,447,427,6,33,429,324,76,396,444,519,159,45,403,243,251,373,251,23,140,7,356,194,499,276,251,311,10,147,30,276,430,151,519,36,354,162,451,524,312,447,77,170,428,23,283,249,466,39,58,424,68,481,2,173,179,382,334,430,84,151,293,95,522,358,505,63,524,143,119,325,401,6,361,284,418,169,256,221,330,23,72,185,376,515,84,319,27,66,497]
```

**Output I am getting with this below code is: 98**

**BUT THE EXPECTED OUTPUT IS 99**

**WHY I AM GETTING THE WRONG OUTPUT?**

**CODE I HAVE DONE:**

```
int findContentChildren(int* g, int gSize, int* s, int sSize){
    if(sSize<1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(gSize<1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int max1=g[0];
    int max2=s[0];
    int max=0;
   for(int i=0;i<gSize;i++)
    {
        if(g[i]==0)
        {
            max++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<gSize;i++)
    {
        if(max1<g[i])
        {
            max1=g[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<sSize;i++)
    {
        if(max2<s[i])
        {
            max2=s[i];
        }
    }
    int hash1[max1+1];
    int hash2[max2+1];
    for(int i=0;i<max1+1;i++)
    {
        hash1[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<max2+1;i++)
    {
        hash2[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<gSize;i++)
    {
        hash1[g[i]]++;
    }
     for(int i=0;i<sSize;i++)
    {
        hash2[s[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<max2+1;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(hash2[i]>0)
        {
            if(i<max1+1)
            {
                if(hash1[i]>0)
                {
                    max++;
                    hash1[i]--;
                     hash2[i]--;
                    i--;
                    
                }
                else
                    for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
                    {
                        if(hash1[j]>0)
                        {
                            max++;
                            hash1[j]--;
                            hash2[i]--;
                            i--;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: If you debug, e.g. by outputting all intermediate vaues of all variables, or like https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , at which point do you see unexpected values?

Comment: If you want StackOverflow users to do the debugging for you, then I recommend at least  providing a [mre]. Generally the recommendations at [ask] are helpful, as would be taking the [tour].

Comment: sind, `if(i==0) { i++;  }` in `for(int i=1;i<max2+1;i++)` loop is unclear as it is never true.  What is this code for?

Comment: Oh, thank you . It is not required.  Even after removing it I am getting the same problem.... I did debug , but I was unable to find the mistake because the input is so long ...

Comment: It isn't entirely clear how this algorithm is supposed to work. Perhaps you should rethink your approach. How about sorting the two arrays? Would it make the problem somewhat more approachable?

Comment: Okay , thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to get the optimal solution using a greedy algorithm?